# Simba Driver Upgrade on Windows

Tags: google-bigquery, driver, simba

I am doing the SIMBA Driver upgrade for our Google SAP Landscape and it seems the procedure for Windows is not clear and quite confusing.
Currently, we have an ODBC Simba driver installed on our Windows machine and we want to upgrade to 3.04.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers

Based on this document:
Simba OEM ODBC Drivers Installation Guide

Windows Simba installation is talking about Installing from a Windows ZIP Package,
from unzip zip file, to copy file to around etc., but from the provided media files, there is only a zip file for Linux and no zip file for Windows. SIMBA Site only has MSI files for Windows.

Can you provide the upgrade procedure from the MSI file? or where to find the Windows zip file media?
My concern here is that directly installing the new version MSI file will mess up the current Windows registry key.